# 'fact of life' and 'necessary evil' difference

Tags: idioms

Are there any differences in the meaning of or when we use the idioms '**fact of life**' and '**necessary evil**'?
The definitions in Cambridge Online Dictionary:

- fact of life: something unpleasant that cannot be avoided
- necessary evil: something unpleasant that must be accepted in order to achieve a particular result

Comment: Please look up the expressions in a good dictionary and let us know what is still causing confusion. ["fact of life"](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/fact-of-life)...["necesary evil"](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/necessary-evil).

Comment: "Fact of life" has a neutral connotation.

Comment: @Rattler I added the definitions to the question. I can't find any special difference in them.

Comment: A necessary evil is a negative activity that leads to a greater good. A fact of life is a more general term per @H.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facts of life tend to happen.  Necessary evils you tend to choose.

Some examples may help.

- Labour pains are...
- Aching joints are...
- Someone cutting you up on the motorway...

Are all facts of life. Things that happen that you just have to deal with.

- The person that killed your brother getting released because they gave evidence against someone worse
- Governments dealing with countries whose ideologies they don't agree with for stability in a region or to protect their citizens

Those are necessary evils.